# What's the most appropriate way to compare dates in this hibernate query?

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

I have a Spring MVC REST service that accepts two `@RequestParam`s called `from` and `to`.  These are parsed as `java.util.Date` and passed to the following method in my DAO class.

```
@Override
public List<ErrorsDTOEntity> getAllErrors(Date from, Date to) {
    try {
        Query query = getSession().createQuery(
                "SELECT NEW com.mydomain.esb.jpa.dto.ErrorsDTOEntity(ee, ec.message) "
                + "FROM ErrorsEntity ee, EventCodeEntity ec "
                + "WHERE ee.responseTime > " + from.getTime() + " "
                + "AND ee.responseTime < " + to.getTime() + " "
                + "AND ee.serviceResponseCode = ec.code "
                + "GROUP BY ee.domainName, ee.serviceName, ec.message, ee.serviceErrorCount, ee.errorTimestamp, "
                + "ee.deviceName, ee.servErrId, ee.serviceResponseCode, ee.elapsedTime, ee.forwardTime, "
                + "ee.responseCompletionTime, ee.responseSizeAverage, ee.requestSizeAverage, ee.responseTime "
                + "ORDER BY ee.domainName, ee.serviceName, ec.message, ee.errorTimestamp");

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<ErrorsDTOEntity> services = (List<ErrorsDTOEntity>) query.list();
        return services;

    } catch (HibernateException hex) {
        hex.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return null;
}
```

This is throwing the following SQL error:

`org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected TIMESTAMP got NUMBER`

What's the proper way to structure this query so I can only fetch results between the `from` and `to` dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, this works:

```
@Override
public List<ErrorsDTOEntity> getAllErrors(Date from, Date to) {
    try {
        Query query = getSession().createQuery(
                "SELECT NEW com.mydomain.esb.jpa.dto.ErrorsDTOEntity(ee, ec.message) "
                + "FROM ErrorsEntity ee, EventCodeEntity ec "
                + "WHERE ee.responseTime > :from "
                + "AND ee.responseTime < :to "
                + "AND ee.serviceResponseCode = ec.code "
                + "GROUP BY ee.domainName, ee.serviceName, ec.message, ee.serviceErrorCount, ee.errorTimestamp, "
                + "ee.deviceName, ee.servErrId, ee.serviceResponseCode, ee.elapsedTime, ee.forwardTime, "
                + "ee.responseCompletionTime, ee.responseSizeAverage, ee.requestSizeAverage, ee.responseTime "
                + "ORDER BY ee.domainName, ee.serviceName, ec.message, ee.errorTimestamp");
        query.setTimestamp("from", from);
        query.setTimestamp("to", to);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<ErrorsDTOEntity> services = (List<ErrorsDTOEntity>) query.list();
        return services;

    } catch (HibernateException hex) {
        hex.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return null;
}
```